# What happens on server when the client/browser quit the page?

Tags: meteor, disconnect

I'm planning to code a server method whose role will be to export a bunch of documents to third party server (dropbox for example). This server method could last several minutes. So I'm asking myself what will happen if the browser disconnect after the server method has been called. The method will stop? The method will continue until the end of the export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session will end, and all methods being executed will come to a premature end as well...